# How to replace the double backslash with a single backslash from share path

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to change the path from

```
"\\\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf"
```

to

```
"\\NDWERE8669\200002679\xyz\xyz_1\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\test.pdf"
```

If I check

```
File.Exists("\\\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf") // returns false
```

Note:

the path is not hardcoded one. this is will be retrieve from the datasource. its all dynamic.

Comment: There are helper classes to build URL's and Paths. You are better of using them, as they actually retreive the rules as used in the current OS. What you coded there might fly as the way on Windows. Or not even there.

Comment: What about `File.Exists(@"\\NDWERE8669\200002679\xyz\xyz_1\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\test.pdf")`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled actually i am retrieving from database. it will stored in the string

Comment: @Christopher Can you suggest some helper class for the same

Comment: Does the database store the backslash doubled already?

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy: Path. Url. No, that really is their name!

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes

Comment: Then you should probably do something like `var result = stringFromDb.Replace("\\\\", "\\");`

Answer (score 4):

This code must also work without replacement "\\" to "\"

```
//is true path
"\\\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf"
```

You can also use the

```
string fileString = "\\\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf";
            fileString=fileString.Replace("\\\\","//").Replace("\\","/");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using existing helper classes, but this works aswell:

```
string fileString = "\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf";
if (File.Exists(filestring))
    filestring = filestring.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Comment: actually i am retrieving from database. it will stored in the string. this is will not help me

Comment: I am not harding the path,

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy Then do this: `stringFromDatabase.Replace("\\\\", "\\");`

Comment: File.Exists("\\\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf").Replace("\\\\", "\\").Replace("\\\\", "\\")). I tried this, But not working

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy Do you understand that File.Exists() returns bool value and you trying to replace string on bool value. Use replace method for string: `File.Exists("\\\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf".Replace("\\\\", "\\"))` see it is called after `pdf".`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the @ makes the string ignore escape chars.

```
   File.Exists(@"\NDWERE8669\200002679\xyz\xyz_1\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\test.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
string strRegex = @"(\\+)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
string strTargetString = 
@"\\\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf";
string strReplace = @"\";

if (File.Exists(@"\" + myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace))) { /* do somthing */
```

Comment: FYI, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex is the fully-qualified method.  Same full qualified code for the options is, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions without string replacing (and safest IMHO) is to use `Path.GetFullPath` method which will normalize the path:

```
var normalizedPath = Path.GetFullPath("\\\\NDWERE8669\\200002679\\xyz\\xyz_1\\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\\test.pdf");
//normalizedPath will be equal to "\\NDWERE8669\200002679\xyz\xyz_1\645d8fa96d254a2ea188a7a9658f5632\test.pdf"
File.Exists(normalizedPath){...}
```